# Origin of LandViewer DEMs?

Tags: dem, resolution

does anyone know how DEMs that can be downloaded from LandViewer are generated?
They have higher resolution than SRTM and other free sources.

Answer (score 1):

[EOS LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer/) offers [Terrain Tiles dataset](https://registry.opendata.aws/terrain-tiles/) provided publicly by Mapzen on AWS S3. The dataset is powered by several major open data sources to achieve high resolution, you can read more here: https://mapzen.com/documentation/terrain-tiles/data-sources/